# Stuck Beginner: Build a Knowledge Graph (involves: API, JSON, existing ontology in turtle format, neo4j)

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, ontology, knowledge-graph

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to build a knowledgegraph for a project from data I'm getting through an API. However, I'm a bit lost in the process and I'm hoping that you guys can possibly help me out here.

**What I have done so far:**

- Implemented a fetch_api function that returns the JSON files for each API entity (Organizations, People, etc.) and stores them in a variable.
- neo4j database connection
- created ontology of a possible knowledgegraph via Protégé and saved it in turtle format

**Considerations to proceed further:**
Now I want to implement the knowledgegraph on the data I have stored in the JSONs in neo4j. For this I am thinking to proceed as follows (and here I am confused):

- use neosemantics (n10s) from Neo4j as a plugin
- use RML.io to map the ontology from the JSONs
- ... what else comes to mind? I am feeling a bit overwhelmed...

**My question is** how to proceed here and in what order. In general, I don't feel I have understood how to build a functional knowledge graph from the JSONs now. Even if I understood how a knowedgegraph is built and of what components it consists.

Since I have sat now several days at the Problem and am really still a complete beginner, I hope that you can help me here (generating next concrete steps I can use as a orientation of going on from here).

Thanks a lot :)

**Your help is very much appreciated!**

I hope that someone can help me here just to see the things again something from the bird's eye view. Then problems usually become obvious much quicker. Just as their solutions.